# usergrid collection permission not working

Tags: apigee, user-permissions, usergrid, apigee-baas

I have created user name `abcdef` and added permission for that user for `concerts` collection as

[image]

When I query for concerts, I expect it to return nothing but it returns all concerts entity. Is there something that I am missing on applying permission

```
curl -XGET 
http://api.usergrid.com/***/***/concerts?access_token\=YWMt8zqr5FqqEeWmj-Oi1e6IqAAAAU_unlN_XnYvv7TeJszcL1o0cEPNYfmWJIw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filed under [`USERGRID-1020`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/USERGRID-1020)

---

There are two reasons that might cause this. **First**, default sandbox permissions may still be set up on your app:

[image]

You'll need to remove this or set them all to `no`.

---

**Second**, and more importantly, applying the permissions directly to the user doesn't appear to be working (?!) and I don't know if this is by design or not. To test this, I duplicated your scenario, and am seeing the same result. To work around it (which actually is more of a security best practice anyway) I created a group with the desired permissions and added the user to the group:

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I'm not in sandbox and when I tried as you said (new group created then I applied permission to that group, then I added one user to that group), it don't work... have you tested result after adding user to group?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the default permission under your app. This worked for me.

[image: BaaS Permission]